# React js memo is not working as expected after passing props from parent to children

Tags: reactjs, render, memoization, memo

Lets say I have a component that maintains the state of some children components. This component holds an `update` function that contains the logic for update the state. I pass the state and the `update` function to the children component, that are `memo`ized. The thing is the state is not being updated, or the state is cleared after the last change is made.

My question is how to proceed with this memoization, due to the real one has a lot of textfield to update.

In [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-jones-bpc7l5?file=/src/App.js) sandbox I reproduce a minimum example.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your update function memorized with **useCallback**

```
const update = useCallback((item, value) => {
    setData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [item]: value,
    }));
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks, but what I really need is to memoize the children component. Although you need to pass `data` into the dependencies array for this callback

Comment: It is possible only with useCallback, because when the children component doesn't take functions as props. Functions are updating after every re-render

Comment: I am telling the component what are the props to observe

Comment: @assembler these links might be helpful for you.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63123846/react-memo-2nd-parameter-dependency-function-not-working-as-expected

Comment: with **prevState** there is no need to pass **data** as an argument for callback

Comment: You know what, your response works charmingly